# understanding the difference Between string permutation Recursive cases

Tags: c#, string, recursion, permutation

```
   class RecursionExample
       {
           private static void doPermute(String str, int l, int r)
            {
                if (l == r)
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                else
                {
                    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
                    {
                        str = swap(str, l, i);
                        doPermute(str, l + 1, r);
                        str = swap(str, l, i);
                    }
                }
            }

            public static String swap(String a,int i, int j)
            {
                char temp;
                char[] charArray = a.ToCharArray();
                temp = charArray[i];
                charArray[i] = charArray[j];
                charArray[j] = temp;
                string s = new string(charArray);
                return s;
            }

            public static void Main()
            {
                String str = "ABC";
                int n = str.Length;
                doPermute(str, 0, n - 1);
            }
     }
```

Compared to

```
class RecursionExample
    {
        private static void doPermute(String str, int l, int r)
        {
            if (l == r)
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            else
            {
                for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
                {
                    str = swap(str, l, i);
                    doPermute(str, l + 1, r);
                }
            }
        }

        public static String swap(String a,int i, int j)
        {
            char temp;
            char[] charArray = a.ToCharArray();
            temp = charArray[i];
            charArray[i] = charArray[j];
            charArray[j] = temp;
            string s = new string(charArray);
            return s;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            String str = "ABC";
            int n = str.Length;
            doPermute(str, 0, n - 1);
        }
 }
```

Both print out the exact same thing, the difference is the first one calls the swap method after the permute recursive call. from what I read online the bottom swap is to "backtrack"
back to the previous case, but it can back track just fine without having to do that extra swap? could someone explain what I am missing or not understanding? for me the bottom one makes more sense to me.

Comment: Post the complete code, without compiler errors

Comment: @TheGeneral i have updated the code

Comment: Where is the blog site, or documentation that said its needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just wasted 5 minutes researching permutation algorithms...

*Back tracking* is only useful when you are working with direct memory or references. Since *strings* are *immutable* in *C#*, the change doesn't get pushed back through the recursive stack, so the *back tracking* isn't useful  for returning the state back to its previous *pre-recursed* state (in essence nothing gets changed anyway).

However, if you to use `ref` (or an array or something of that ilk) you would not only find your input being mutated, worse still you would receive the wrong result.

**Example**

```
private static void doPermute(ref string str, int l, int r)
{
   if (l == r)
      Console.WriteLine(str);
   else
   {
      for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
      {
         str = swap(str, l, i);
         doPermute(ref str, l + 1, r);
         str = swap(str, l, i);

      }
   }
}
```

**Output with backtracking**

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB
```

**Output without backtracking**

```
ABC
ACB
CAB
CBA
ABC
ACB
```

In summary, it serves no purposes if you are not using direct memory or references.

Comment: Ahhh I understand now, unless you are passing by reference there is no need for it. haven't dealt with passing by ref for a while so I was really confused on this but this makes sense thank you!